# Redirect the same connection multiple times [IPTABLES]

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, firewall, ubuntu-14.04

Im trying to redirect the TCP connections a port multiple times to another ports, i tried this before but didn't work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 60000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 60001
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 60001 -j REDIRECT --to-port 60002
```

I'm trying to get port 6000 to redirect tcp connections to port 60001, then port 60001 will redirect the connection to port 60002.

X -> Y -> Z

what can I do?

Comment: I know there must be a reason, but can you tell why don't you redirect 6000 to 6002 directly? And maybe something about the use case?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani i will mitigate bot attacks

60000 -> 60001 (mitigate) -> 60002 (game server)

Comment: In what is this question different from https://serverfault.com/questions/1019744/im-trying-to-redirect-some-ports-with-iptables ?

Comment: So for the 3rd time I write again the same comment: On Linux you cannot NAT (redirect) with conntrack a flow that is already redirected with conntrack. I would write an answer to tell "no" (and give the technical reason)but I'm not sure that will help.

Comment: @A.B the hitcount on this question dont exist, on this question is more elaborate and easier to understand my difficulty.

How can i redirect 1 port multime times like X -> Y -> Z?

Comment: Check this: http://xyproblem.info/ ,  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Please do not blank your questions out when solved.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 2):

Your mitigate step needs to forward the connection to your game server, you cannot do this with IPTables.

Comment: So, what tool i can use to do that?

Comment: I don't know know of any tool for that, I just know the principle what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match the same packet twice with different DNAT rules. But you can make the whole structure more complicated and thus more flexible.

You can create a chain for each destination port you want to handle:

```
iptables -t nat -N port60000
iptables -t nat -N port60001
```

If you match a packet you do not send it to the DNAT target but to the respective chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 60000 -j port60000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 60001 -j port60001
```

In the original state the chains do the same as the old commands, just a bit more slowly...

```
iptables -t nat -A port60000 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination :60001
iptables -t nat -A port60001 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination :60002
```

If you want to change `60000 => 60001` to `60000 => 60002` then you can change the content of `port60000`:

```
iptables -t nat -A port60000 -p tcp -j port60001
iptables -t nat -D port60000 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination :60001
```

But that this is possible does not mean that this is better than recreating the rules after a change.